# How to use dynamic duration value in Output Caching?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, output-caching

I'm using ASP.NET MVC3.
I've used Output Caching on controller method.

```
   [OutputCache(Duration = 3660, VaryByParam = "none")]
   public ActionResult Index()
   {
       some code;
       return View();
   }
```

I want to put dynamic duration using some static variable or something else in Output Caching.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would inherit from the `OutputCache` attribute and set there the `Duration`:

```
public static class CacheConfig
{
    public static int Duration = 36600;
}

public class MyOutputCacheAttribute : OutputCacheAttribute
{
    public MyOutputCacheAttribute()
    {
        this.Duration = CacheConfig.Duration;
    }
}

[MyOutputCache(VaryByParam = "none")]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

Then you can change the `Duration` dynamically and globally trough the `CacheConfig.Duration`

And you can still override the global setting on every action if you want:

```
[MyOutputCache(Duration = 100, VaryByParam = "none")]
public ActionResult OtherAction()
{
    return View();
}
```

Comment: Won't work, attributes are instantiated only ONCE, changing `CacheConfig.Duration` at *runtime* won't magically re-execute your constructor