# How can I use [OutputCache (Duration=2000)] with variable duration value and reset Server cache

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, outputcache, output-caching

I have the code below and want `Duration` in `[OutputCache(Duration = 10)]` line to have a variable value so that I can read it from `DB` or from a `List` Collection.

And **I want be able to reset the server cache immediately, when `Duration` had changed.**

How can I make `Duration` varied and reset cached `HTML` data when the `Duration` is changed? Here is my code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Cache_Example.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {

        // GET: Home
       // [OutputCache(Duration = 10)]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [OutputCache(Duration = 10)]
        public ActionResult ShowDate()
        {
            return PartialView();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you can not, you would need to implement your own cache, with your requirement built around it

Comment: -@Jeremy Thompson, why in edit heading of question: `reset Server catch? (in ASP.Net MVC by C#)`, the `(in ASP.Net MVC by C#)` was deleted?

Comment: Hi, there a good reason why I did that: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190/156316, Google & etc read the tags so when you Google you just prefix your search with the tags. It's a heaps better way than free-text. I removed the server **catch**, because it's is spelled *cache*.

Comment: -@Jeremy Thompson, Regard and thanks, I meant that `(in ASP.Net MVC by C#)` why removed?

Comment: `(in ASP.Net MVC by C#)` is better specified in tags (indexed by search engines) than free-text in a title.

Comment: Understand. Thankful.

Comment: You can create your own functionality by playing with source  :P (WARNING: You may spoil your life) https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Mvc/OutputCacheAttribute.cs

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To change the duration follow this:

[How to use dynamic duration value in Output Caching?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10426843/how-to-use-dynamic-duration-value-in-output-caching) *(please credit original author)*

> I would inherit from the `OutputCache` attribute and set the `Duration`:

```
public static class CacheConfig
{
    public static int Duration = 36600;
}

public class MyOutputCacheAttribute : OutputCacheAttribute
{
    public MyOutputCacheAttribute()
    {
        this.Duration = CacheConfig.Duration;
    }
}

[MyOutputCache(VaryByParam = "none")]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

Then you can change the `Duration` dynamically and globally through the `CacheConfig.Duration`

And you can still override the global setting on every action if you want:

```
[MyOutputCache(Duration = 100, VaryByParam = "none")]
public ActionResult OtherAction()
{
    return View();
}
```

---

Then you can reset the server cache immediately when Duration has changed yourself. Here's how:

"The ASP.NET cache object is located in the System.Web namespace, and because it is a generic cache implementation, it can be used in any application that references this namespace.

The System.Web.Caching.Cache class is a cache of objects. It is accessed either through the static property System.Web.HttpRuntime.Cache or through the helper instance properties System.Web.UI.Page and System.Web.HttpContext.Cache. It is therefore available outside the context of a request. There is only one instance of this object throughout an entire application domain, so the HttpRuntime.Cache object can exist in each application domain outside of Aspnet_wp.exe.

The following code shows how you can access the ASP.NET cache object from a generic application.

```
HttpRuntime httpRT = new HttpRuntime();
Cache cache = HttpRuntime.Cache;
```

After you access the cache object for the current request, you can use its members in the usual way."

REF: Obsolete MSDN Source: [Caching Architecture Guide for .NET Framework Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Ee817647%28pandp.10%29.aspx)

Note: With .Net 3.5 you could only use InProc cache, with .NET 4 you can store your cache outside the process as well as using custom [CacheProviders](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/performance/caching-in-net-framework-applications).

I want to emphasize this point, if the cache is supposed to last longer than the AppPool recycles (eg daily) then you need to cache Out-Of-Process.

---

Also check its being cached on the server:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.outputcachelocation.aspx

Comment: With regard, Please note that, The above original question contains addition matter than [How to use dynamic duration value in Output Caching?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10426843/how-to-use-dynamic-duration-value-in-output-caching); revise your question and don't copy another; with pay attention (How can reset Server catch?) part of original question.

Comment: Unless i'm missing something, this is not what OP wants. This just sets a global default for cache, but can't be changed dynamically. CacheConfig.Duration will be copied to each instance of MyOutputCacheAttribute, and updating it will not take effect.